# Как получить информацию из диалогового окна?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Всем добрый день.

Как сделать так, чтобы диалоговое окно вернуло введенную информацию?

Я сейчас делаю так:

```
def build_exel_registration(self):
    info = ExelInfo()  # Создаю экземпляр диалогового окна
    info.exec()  # Ставлю этот скрипт на паузу (Не понимаю как это работает)
    if info.ok:  # Смотрю переменную диалогового окна, проверяя нажал кнопку ok или cancel
        name = info.name.text()  # Беру имя из строки ввода

# Класс диалогового окна
class ExelInfo(QDialog, exel_info_class):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    super(ExelInfo, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setModal(True)
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(getcwd() + "/images/icon.ico"))
    self.show()

  def accept(self):  # Если нажата кнопка Ok
    self.ok = True
    self.close()

  def rect(self):  # Если нажата кнопка cancel
    self.ok = False
    self.close()
```

Но хотелось бы что бы это выглядело по человечески.
Например что бы диалоговое окно возвращала сразу имя, например:

```
name = ExelInfo()
```

Можно ли так сделать?

Ведь QMessageBox примерно так и работает!

Comment: `ExelInfo()` возвращает объект типа  `ExelInfo`, он не может вернуть `name`, которое `str`  (или `unicode`)—точнее не рекомендуется пытаться создавать класс, который наследует от `QDialog` и `str` одновременно. Насколько я понимаю, у вас уже есть  метод, который достаёт необходимую информацию (`build_exel_registration()`). Дайте ему более человеческое имя: `name = ask_name()` и добавьте `return name` внутри. Или вас интересует более простая реализация?

Comment: Щас объясню как все есть.
Функция build_exel_registration создает exel фаил о принятии работника на работу!
Но для того что бы создать этот фаил мне нужно ими работника, которое я запрашиваю в диалоговом окне ExelInfo.

Answer (score 1):

```
> name = ExelInfo()
```

> Можно ли так сделать?
>
> Ведь QMessageBox примерно так и работает!

Вот так нельзя. Но можно как и в `QMessageBox` сделать статичный метод и из него вызывать диалог и возвращать значение, например:

```
class ExelInfo(QDialog, exel_info_class):
    # ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_name():
        info = ExelInfo()
        info.exec()

        if info.ok:
            return info.name.text()
```

И использование:

```
name = ExelInfo.get_name()
```